# What happened to the mzlatex command?

Tags: miktex, htlatex, latex2html

I am using MiKTeX 2.9.

I would like to convert a LaTeX file to HTML.

I have seen here (http://access2science.com/latex/tutorial_txht.xhtml#x1-50001.2) that I can use the `mzlatex` command to convert this way but I get the following error:

> `mzlatex` is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

It is mentioned in the above link (http://access2science.com/latex/tutorial_txht.xhtml#x1-50001.2) that MiKTeX 2.9 has some problem and so I have to install version 2.8 but I do not see MiKTeX 2.8 giving following message:

> MiKTeX 2.8 has been released in September 2009.This version has reached the "end-of-life" status. It will not be possible to install packages from the remote package repository.The current release is 2.9.

(http://miktex.org/2.8/status)

I am not sure What I am supposed to do now.

I tried  but it is giving following error:

[image]

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60230/15925 help?

Comment: as @AndrewSwann said, mzlatex is not standalone script, you can use `mk4ht mzlatex`

Comment: @AndrewSwann : I tried mk4ht mzlatex... but it is saying undefined control sequence... :O please have a look at my edit

Comment: @AndrewSwann : please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164670/convert-tex-file-to-html-in-miktex this question too

Comment: According to your screenshot you have written the command in the wrong order, it is asking for `mk4ht mzlatex yourtexfile` as michal.h21 said.

Comment: @AndrewSwann : Oh yes yes... I have tried as you suggested but it is saying undefined control sequence :O

Comment: I am not a windows user but your file name contains special tex characters, so you probably need to quote the whole name `"E:\file_name"`

Comment: @AndrewSwann : I do not understand the point :O I am trying all combinations but nothing is working :(

Comment: The point is that tex regards `_` as a special math character.  The output you have now posted shows that this character in the filename is the problem.  I suggested you change the name of your file so it contains only ordinary letters.

Comment: @AndrewSwann : I have changed the file name and end up with same problem... I have my miktex file in C drive and my tex files in E drive... would that be a problem? I have moved the files to C drive even then i am getting same messgae

Comment: You still need to either cd to the directory where your tex file is or quote the whole name...

Comment: @AndrewSwann The problem is solved now :) I got the html code... Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: You could provide a perfect self-answer I guess. `mzlatex` is not known to MiKTeX, but it does not exist in TeX Live for Windows either.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure the current path is that of the file `test.tex` to convert, use

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex" test.tex "html,mathml"`

instead, as explained in [TeX4ht (htlatex) on MiKTeX 2.9 to convert LaTeX into MathML, and then into Office MathML with Word 2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197913/tex4ht-htlatex-on-miktex-2-9-to-convert-latex-into-mathml-and-then-into-offic?lq=1) and [MiKTeX 2.9's tex4ht not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60230/miktex-2-9s-tex4ht-not-working?lq=1).

Alternatively, try

`htlatex test.tex "xhtml,mozilla" "-cmozhtf"`,

pretty much equivalent to `mzlatex`, as explained in https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/share/doc/tex4ht/html/.