# TeX4ht (htlatex) on MiKTeX 2.9 to convert LaTeX into MathML, and then into Office MathML with Word 2010

Tags: miktex, tex4ht, html, htlatex, latex-to-word

I managed to use TeX4ht via the `htlatex` command on MiKTeX 2.9 to successfully convert a LaTeX document into an HTML document. The TeX file is a fairly simple test document with an integral in display format. However, I'm using this method as an indirect means to ultimately convert LaTeX into Word with Office MathML (OMML) math. The idea is to convert the TEX file into HTML, and then to simply open the HTML in Word 2010 and save it as DOCX.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to manage to do the entire conversion of LaTeX/TEX into MathML/HTML into Office MathML/DOCX properly. I do manage to get a nice HTML, but that's where I'm stuck.

Here's what I tried. Without options, `htlatex` generates a picture in PNG format rather than MathML embedded in the HTML file. Word keeps the picture and no OMML is created.

`htlatex` with the option "html,mathml" creates an HTML file with MathML, without a bitmap figure, but Word 2010 cannot read it properly, and the resulting formulas look crudely changed into text with greek letters and in-line symbols.

The option "xhtml,mathml" also gives problems, something along the lines of "DTD prohibited", when opening in Word the HTML file. Tried "xhtml,oofice,mathml" with similar luck.

I wonder if I should use `mk4h mzlatex` instead of `htlatex`. I haven't tested this alternative because `mk4h` on Windows seems to require a Perl interpreter, and it seems pretty much equivalent to `htlatex` with the option "xhtml,mozilla" anyway, as indicated in https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/i386_deb50/os-ubuntu-9.04/usr/share/doc/tex4ht/html/. `htlatex` doesn't require Perl.

DETAILS

1. Installed MiKTeX 2.9 with both `miktex-tex4ht-bin-2.9` and `miktex-tex4ht-base-2.9` installed with the package manager in administrator mode, on Windows 7.
2. Created a `test.tex` file in `E:\downloads`, as follows:

   ```
   \documentclass{report}
   \begin{document}
   Hello there. This is a test of $x_i^2=3$, where
   $$\int_0^\infty f(x) = 1.$$
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Converted the TeX file into an HTML file with the following MS DOS commands. It is important to note that as htlatex accepts filenames but not pathnames, it is important to set the current directory to where the tex file resides. If a pathname were given for the test file, e.g., e:\downloads\test.tex, the error "undefined command sequence" would be produced.

   ```
   e:
   cd Downloads
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex.bat" test.tex
   ```
4. The conversion is successful, but the integral formula appears as a bitmap file, instead of being embedded as MathML.
5. Tried the following instead, which does generate the Math ML code instead of the image, but Word 2010 cannot recognize it properly and convert it into Office Math ML:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex" test.tex "html,mathml"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I had success at opening your document with Word 2010. First of all, I converted document to `odt` format. Because you don't have `mk4ht` command available, you need to use following `htlatex` call:

```
htlatex test.tex "xhtml,ooffice" "ooffice/! -cmozhtf" "-cooxtpipes -coo"
```

all these parameters are necessary, they are used in postprocessing of the `xml` file with document.

When I tried to open resulting document with `Word 2010`, only crossed gray boxes were shown in the place of math. Then I tried to open and then save `test.odt` with `OpenOffice` (3.2) and `LibreOffice` (3.6). In both cases, saved file was much almost twice as big. Document saved in `OpenOffice` was opened without problems in `Word`, document saved in `LibreOffice` reported incorrect content, but then `Word` asked if I want to repair it and then opened it correctly as well.

I took a look at `odt` files saved from `Open/LibreOfficess` and it seems that math was extracted from the main document and it each math fragment was saved in standalone file with some additional metadata. While `Open/LibreOffice` is fine with `odt` files produced by `tex4ht`, word obviously isn't and its `odt` support needs to have math in particular format. I don't know whether this behaviour shows also current `Word` version and it is probably a bug in `odt` support in `Word`, but I don't know `odt` standard well enough to judge that. If your `Word` doesn't support math in `odt` files produced by `tex4ht` try to open and save it with `OpenOffice`.

[image]

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer. It was really nice of you to take the trouble to do all of this. Unfortunately, the execution of the `htlatex` command with the specific options you mention produces an error in my computer. Further, I have Word installed, but not OpenOffice or other variants (and that's probably the reason why :)). The error in question is: Searching `cmsy.htf' for `cmbsy5.htf'
(C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/cm/cmsy.htf)
--- error --- Illegal storage address

Comment: @JBloggs this error message is known `tex4ht` error in miktex. see this thread: http://tug.org/pipermail/tex4ht/2011q2/000312.html

Comment: you can try to run following commands: `tex4ht test ooffice/! -cmozhtf` and `t4ht test -cooxtpipes -coo`. Illefal storage adress is caused by wrong escaping of arguments

Comment: if you don't want to install openoffice, you may send me the resulting odt file to my mail (michal dot h21 at gmail dot com) and I will update it

Comment: Thanks so much, but now that I see that it's not an easy process, didn't manage to make it work, and it involves several pieces of software, I think I'll try better luck with some of the commercial tools for LaTeX-to-Word conversion. Perhaps GrindEQ, not sure.