# Pandoc command line to make bibliography

Tags: biblatex, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

```
pandoc Article.tex --from=latex --to=docx --biblatex --bibliography="bibliography.bib" --output=Article.docx
```

As per [tex to docx via pandoc with ACM template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197998/tex-to-docx-via-pandoc-with-acm-template)

Fails to actually produce the bibliography.

What I am missing in the command line?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french,german,italian,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,autocite=footnote,citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false,opcittracker=false,sorting=nyt,notetype=foot+end]{biblatex}
\usapackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bib}

@Book{Woolf:1913,
  author      = {C. N. S. Woolf},
  title       = {Bartolus of Sassoferrato: His Position in the History of Medieval Political Thought},
  address     = {Cambridge},
  publisher   = {Cambridge University Press},
  year        = {1913},
  language    = {english},
  hyphenation = {english},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\autocite{Woolf:1913}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing some minor issues in your MWE, the following works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,french,german,italian,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,autocite=footnote,citetracker=true,ibidtracker=false,opcittracker=false,sorting=nyt,notetype=foot+end]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{Article.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{Article.bib}

@Book{Woolf:1913,
  author      = {C. N. S. Woolf},
  title       = {Bartolus of Sassoferrato: His Position in the History of Medieval Political Thought},
  address     = {Cambridge},
  publisher   = {Cambridge University Press},
  year        = {1913},
  language    = {english},
  hyphenation = {english},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\autocite{Woolf:1913}

\end{document}
```

Call:

```
pandoc Article.tex \
    --from=latex --to=docx \
    --filter=pandoc-citeproc --bibliography=Article.bib \
    --output=Article.docx
```

Which gives you:

[image]

If you need a different citation style, download the right `.csl`-file from [Zotero Style Repository](https://www.zotero.org/styles) and add the option `--csl=filename.csl`