# Latex to DOCX converter

Tags: latex-to-word

I use PDFlatex to compile my tex file. I want to convert in DOCX to send it to my thesis supervisor. I'm using Acrobat XI PRO to convert PDF into DOCX, but the result isn't good. The language is undetect, and the equation doesn't appear correctly, especially the root square. Please help me.

Comment: you really don't want to do this. converting from tex to docx is massively error prone and likely to require hand edits and fixes at each stage.  For a final document it might be worth it, but not on every cycle as the thesis develops. Try to persuade your supervisor to accept the pdf, and if he won't, just do the thesis in word.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197989/2891 `tex4ht` can produce office document with math, but due to some bug, the file must be opened and then saved with libreoffice. then math is preserved when the file is opened in word

Comment: I don't use miktex, but texlives 2014. I won't a professional and perfect result, but only a well-formatted result, with the equation showed (I accept that the equation in .png format, not editable)