# What's the problem with this code? Overfull \hbox

Tags: formatting, amsmath, matrices, multirow, width

I want to create something like this in word by `MathType 6.9`
[image]
But I have `MikTex 2.9` and `texmaker` installed on my computer. Just to try out the code and see what is wrong with that, I've created the following document in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
T_4 &= \langle \underline{k}\,.\,\underline{k}^{*^T} \rangle=
\left\langle 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\left|k_1\right|^2 & k_1k_2^* & k_1k_3^* & k_1k_4^*\\
k_2k_1^* & \left|k_2\right|^2 & k_2k_3^* & k_2k_4^*\\
k_3k_1^* & k_3k_2^* & \left|k_3\right|^2 & k_3k_4^*\\
k_4k_1^* & k_4k_2^* & k_4k_3^* & \left|k_4\right|^2
\end{bmatrix} 
\right\rangle
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{split}
\left[\begin{matrix}
\langle|S_{XX}+S_{YY}|^2\rangle & 
\langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &\\
\langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle & 
\langle|S_{XX}-S_{YY}|^2\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
\langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle& 
\langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle & 
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &
\end{matrix}\right.\\
\left.\begin{matrix}
& \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle 
& \langle -j(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\cdots\cdots& \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle 
& \langle -j(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\cdots\cdots& \langle|S_{XY}+S_{YX}|^2\rangle 
& \langle-j(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
& \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle 
& \langle|S_{XY}-S_{YX}|^2\rangle
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

But there's a warning `Overfull \hbox (213.43704pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 39--39`.
Line 39 is `\end{align}`
and the created pdf is like this:
[image]
I also deleted the document parts and tried out the code from `begin{align}` to `end{aline}` in MathType 6.9 but there it is like this:

[image]

It seems that `begin{split}` and `end{split}` is making something wrong!!!
What should I do?

Comment: the mathtype specific parts of the question are off topic for this forum, mathtype does not use tex. like many other tex-to-xx convertors it reads a small subset of tex-like syntax. there may be other sites in teh stackexchange network that are more suitable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can you suggest me a site in stack exchange where I can ask my mathtype related question?

Comment: No sorry I know nothing about it at all, you could try the main stack overflow one, but it's not tex related

Comment: Does `multline` exist in MathType? If so, try replacing `align` with `multline`, and remove `\begin{split}` and `\end{split}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `aligned` environment instead of `split` there is no problem, especially if you add the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  T_4 &= \langle \underline{k}\,.\,\underline{k}^{*^T} \rangle=
  \left\langle
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \left|k_1\right|^2 & k_1k_2^* & k_1k_3^* & k_1k_4^* \\
  k_2k_1^* & \left|k_2\right|^2 & k_2k_3^* & k_2k_4^* \\
  k_3k_1^* & k_3k_2^* & \left|k_3\right|^2 & k_3k_4^* \\
  k_4k_1^* & k_4k_2^* & k_4k_3^* & \left|k_4\right|^2
  \end{bmatrix}
  \right\rangle
  \\
  &=\frac{1}{2}
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
  & \left[\begin{matrix}
  \langle|S_{XX}+S_{YY}|^2\rangle &
  \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &\\
  \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle &
  \langle|S_{XX}-S_{YY}|^2\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
  \langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle&
  \langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle & \cdots\cdots\\
  \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle &
  \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &
  \end{matrix}\right.\\
  & \left.\begin{matrix}
  & \langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
  & \langle -j(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
  \cdots\cdots& \langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
  & \langle -j(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
  \cdots\cdots& \langle|S_{XY}+S_{YX}|^2\rangle
  & \langle-j(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
  & \langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle
  & \langle|S_{XY}-S_{YX}|^2\rangle
  \end{matrix}\right]
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes you are right. Both your code and Tarass's work in Latex environment but when I want to add them in MS word with the help of Mathtype they do not work. In fact it seems that Mathtype does not have the ability to parse some codes of Latex to equations of word. And my main problem is I need this MS word document and I should submit it to my professor. Do you know of any way other than Mathtype to directly enter latex equations into MS Word?

Comment: But Mathtype doesn't parse simple amsmath code?

Comment: seems that it does not. I'm now searching the site to find other way than mathtype or to export .doxc from latex and then copy-paste the equation into my thesis document

Comment: both of you and Tarass's code are excellent. Especially when I add `unpackage{geometry}`, there's not even a warning. Both Mathtype doesn't parse :(

Comment: Maybe Word would understand `mathml`? Or includig the equation as a .pdf image (so that it remains zoomable).

Comment: and I don't understand `mathml` [here's](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8836/producing-doc-docx-from-latex?rq=1) maybe the solution. what does it mean `ran the .tex-Files through htlatex` in the first answer with 40 votes which is answered by Habi

Comment: `htlatex` is a script from `TeX4ht` that converts TeX files to html, using MathML. I don't know if you've seen [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197913/tex4ht-htlatex-on-miktex-2-9-to-convert-latex-into-mathml-and-then-into-offic)

Comment: Judging by the screenshot upon which the OP came up with the sample code, I have a hunch that `\cdot` should be used instead of `\,.\,`. I also suspect that `\underline{k}^{*^T}` should be replaced with `\underline{k}^{*T}`.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt}
$\begin{array}{rclc}
T_4 &=& \langle \underline{k}\,.\,\underline{k}^{*^T} \rangle=
\left\langle 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\left|k_1\right|^2 & k_1k_2^* & k_1k_3^* & k_1k_4^*\\
k_2k_1^* & \left|k_2\right|^2 & k_2k_3^* & k_2k_4^*\\
k_3k_1^* & k_3k_2^* & \left|k_3\right|^2 & k_3k_4^*\\
k_4k_1^* & k_4k_2^* & k_4k_3^* & \left|k_4\right|^2
\end{bmatrix} 
\right\rangle
&(1)\\ \\[-.5em]
&=&\frac{1}{2}
\left[\begin{matrix}
\langle|S_{XX}+S_{YY}|^2\rangle & 
\langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &\\
\langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle & 
\langle|S_{XX}-S_{YY}|^2\rangle & \cdots\\
\langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle& 
\langle(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle & \cdots\\
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}+S_{YY})^*\rangle & 
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XX}-S_{YY})^*\rangle &
\end{matrix}\right.
\\ &&&(2)\\[-.5em]
&&\hfill
\left.\begin{matrix}
\langle(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle &
\langle -j(S_{XX}+S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\langle(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle &
\langle -j(S_{XX}-S_{YY})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\langle|S_{XY}+S_{YX}|^2\rangle &
\langle-j(S_{XY}+S_{YX})(S_{XY}-S_{YX})^*\rangle\\
\langle j(S_{XY}-S_{YX})(S_{XY}+S_{YX})^*\rangle &
\langle|S_{XY}-S_{YX}|^2\rangle
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{array}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice answer for latex but not for mathtype an thus can not be entered in MS word as an equation

Comment: I had a doubt if you are using MS word or latex. Could you crop the produced pdf and include it in your Word document ?

Comment: that will be a photo of the equation. and as you know for scientific journals we should submit editable equations. Don't you know of any way other than Mathtype to import your latex code as an editable equation in MS word? Because right now I'm not very well in Latex and I can not write whole my thesis with Latex. So I need a way to enter equations written by latex in Ms word

Comment: If you can use Libre Office instead of MS, you can install TexMaths here :http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/texmaths-1. Then double click on the `pi` icone and past the code between begin and end document. The result is perfect. I just Tried. See the new photo in my answer.

Comment: Libre Office just works for Linux? or does it have a windows version?

Comment: If you select the picture in LO, ans click the `pi` icone, you can edit again your code. I maybe exists something like that in MS word otherwise use LO.

Comment: Both linux, Windows, Mac - what is both for three ?

Comment: LO creates .docx format?

Comment: can you chat for a minute? I have my final problem http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26787/use-latex-in-ms-word

Comment: @ Tarass can you?

Comment: I'm on my cellphone. In one till now.

Comment: I wait for you in the chat room you said.