# Need to convert Latex document to Word. Using Mathtype but equations use \newcommand terms. Will Mathype understand?

Tags: msword, open-office

I'm trying to convert my Latex document + equations to word document and I'm using Mathtype. I've tried some of the .tex to word converts, htlatex etc and it just doesn't work and its going to be quicker to do it myself.

However all my latex documents use my own commands via "newcommand" so that I can change symbols thought the entire document quickly. For example:

```
\newcommands{\partial_flux}{\phi}
\newcommands{\Real_Space}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommands{\Cartesian_coord_1}{x}
```

Then my equation would be something like:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
\partial_flux(\Cartesian_coord_1) \in \Real_Space
\end{aligned}  
\end{equation}
```

With open office there is a package called TexMath and its allows one to give it the list of \newcommands under the tab called "preamble". Then one simply pastes the latex equations, clicks the convert button and it all works great.

I cannot use Open office and must instead use word, so is there a way in which I can do this within word?

Comment: This is really a question about MathType/Word isn't it? That makes it off-topic here, I think.  Saving the document in OpenOffice in Word's format doesn't work? Another thing you could try is to run a script that replaces all your macros with their definitions, see e.g. [Is there a script that reads a TeX file and replaces every instance of a \newcommand?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67709)

Comment: when you want to convert to Word, you should use command `mk4ht oolatex filename`. this will create the `.odt` file. It can be then saved as Word document in LibreOffice. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197989/2891

Comment: Hi michal.h21 many thanks, I have tried to use both mk4ht and htlatex and while everything runs fine I don't seem to have a .odt file! I've also tried the command line in given in the link and against runs but no .odt is produced.

Comment: `\newcommands{\Cartesian_coord_1}{x}` would not work in latex, the command is `\newcommand` not `\newcommands` and commands so defined can not use `_` or `1` in their name. Do you really expect some other convertor to accept this syntax?

Comment: (related question: [conversion - Workflow for converting LaTeX into Open Office / MS Word Format - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format)