# Problem when use htlatex converting LaTeX to HTML

Tags: miktex, html, htlatex

I now need convert LaTeX to HTML using MiKTeX, and then to Word finally. There is no output html file at all, i followed the step from JBloggs [TeX4ht (htlatex) on MiKTeX 2.9 to convert LaTeX into MathML, and then into Office MathML with Word 2010](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197913/tex4ht-htlatex-on-miktex-2-9-to-convert-latex-into-mathml-and-then-into-offic). But still i do not have the html output file.

**the tex file**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
Hello there. This is a test of $x_i^2=3$, where
$$\int_0^\infty f(x) = 1.$$
\end{document}
```

**the conversion commands i tried**

```
"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex.bat" test.tex 

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htxelatex.bat" test.tex 

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex" test.tex "html,xml"

C:\Documents htlatex test.tex "html,word"

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htxelatex" test

htlatex test.tex  "xhtml,mathml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"
```

the last one was suggested by MadyYuvi

**the compiling result**

```
ar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode html.a.b.c.\input  test.
tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\test.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latex209.def"

          Entering LaTeX 2.09 COMPATIBILITY MODE
 *************************************************************
    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!

 This mode attempts to provide an emulation of the LaTeX 2.09
 author environment so that OLD documents can be successfully
 processed. It should NOT be used for NEW documents!

 New documents should use Standard LaTeX conventions and start
 with the \documentclass command.

 Compatibility mode is UNLIKELY TO WORK with LaTeX 2.09 style
 files that change any internal macros, especially not with
 those that change the FONT SELECTION or OUTPUT ROUTINES.

 Therefore such style files MUST BE UPDATED to use
          Current Standard LaTeX: LaTeX2e.
 If you suspect that you may be using such a style file, which
 is probably very, very old by now, then you should attempt to
 get it updated by sending a copy of this error message to the
 author of that file.
 *************************************************************

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\tracefnt.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latexsym.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mff.sty"
LaTeX Style file MFF.STY, ver. 1.21 [June 1996]
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfdcdata.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfsauter.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfcorfnt.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mftricks.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfarithm.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(test.tmp) (test.xref)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex209.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")) (test.aux)
<MFF/line=11>: No file xxz15.tfm -- dummy font will be used
<MFF/line=11>: Do not forget to process xxz15.mf and reprocess this file
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\table.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ulasy.fd") [1] (test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 69412 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

E:\>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode
\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1
.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\
HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\c
sname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextch
ar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode html.a.b.c.\input  test.
tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\test.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latex209.def"

          Entering LaTeX 2.09 COMPATIBILITY MODE
 *************************************************************
    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!

 This mode attempts to provide an emulation of the LaTeX 2.09
 author environment so that OLD documents can be successfully
 processed. It should NOT be used for NEW documents!

 New documents should use Standard LaTeX conventions and start
 with the \documentclass command.

 Compatibility mode is UNLIKELY TO WORK with LaTeX 2.09 style
 files that change any internal macros, especially not with
 those that change the FONT SELECTION or OUTPUT ROUTINES.

 Therefore such style files MUST BE UPDATED to use
          Current Standard LaTeX: LaTeX2e.
 If you suspect that you may be using such a style file, which
 is probably very, very old by now, then you should attempt to
 get it updated by sending a copy of this error message to the
 author of that file.
 *************************************************************

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\tracefnt.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latexsym.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mff.sty"
LaTeX Style file MFF.STY, ver. 1.21 [June 1996]
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfdcdata.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfsauter.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfcorfnt.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mftricks.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfarithm.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(test.tmp) (test.xref)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex209.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")) (test.aux)
<MFF/line=11>: No file xxz15.tfm -- dummy font will be used
<MFF/line=11>: Do not forget to process xxz15.mf and reprocess this file
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\table.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ulasy.fd") [1] (test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 69412 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

E:\>latex  \makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx"\HCode
\def\HCode"##1"{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1
.a.b.c.{\g@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\
HCode\documentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\c
sname tex4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextch
ar[{\HCode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode html.a.b.c.\input  test.
tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\test.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latex209.def"

          Entering LaTeX 2.09 COMPATIBILITY MODE
 *************************************************************
    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!    !!WARNING!!

 This mode attempts to provide an emulation of the LaTeX 2.09
 author environment so that OLD documents can be successfully
 processed. It should NOT be used for NEW documents!

 New documents should use Standard LaTeX conventions and start
 with the \documentclass command.

 Compatibility mode is UNLIKELY TO WORK with LaTeX 2.09 style
 files that change any internal macros, especially not with
 those that change the FONT SELECTION or OUTPUT ROUTINES.

 Therefore such style files MUST BE UPDATED to use
          Current Standard LaTeX: LaTeX2e.
 If you suspect that you may be using such a style file, which
 is probably very, very old by now, then you should attempt to
 get it updated by sending a copy of this error message to the
 author of that file.
 *************************************************************

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\tracefnt.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\latexsym.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\usepackage.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mff.sty"
LaTeX Style file MFF.STY, ver. 1.21 [June 1996]
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfdcdata.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfsauter.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfcorfnt.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mftricks.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\mfarithm.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.4ht"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 TeX4ht info is available in the log file
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\tex4ht.sty"
--- needs --- tex4ht test ---
(test.tmp) (test.xref)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\fontmath.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\latex209.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\article.4ht"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4.4ht")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\tex4ht\html4-math.4ht")) (test.aux)
<MFF/line=11>: No file xxz15.tfm -- dummy font will be used
<MFF/line=11>: Do not forget to process xxz15.mf and reprocess this file
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\mff\table.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ulasy.fd") [1] (test.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 69412 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.

E:\>tex4ht test.tex  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/ -ewin32/tex4ht.env
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 Windows MiKTeX)
tex4ht test.tex
  -i/tex4ht/ht-fonts/
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/1/charset/unicode.4hf)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmtt8.tfm)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/cm/cmtt.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmtt.htf' for `cmtt8.htf'
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmtt.htf)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmtt10.tfm)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/cm/cmtt.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmtt.htf' for `cmtt10.htf'
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmtt.htf)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr12.tfm)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/lm/lm-rep-cmrm/cmr.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmrm.htf' for `cmr12.htf'
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmrm.htf)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/alias/lm/lm-rep-cmrm/cmr.htf)
Searching `lm-rep-cmrm.htf' for `cmr10.htf'
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/lm/lm-rep-cmrm.htf)
[1 file test.html
 file test.css
 file test.tmp
]
Execute script `test.lg'

E:\>t4ht test.tex  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:28 MiKTeX)
t4ht test.tex
  -ewin32/tex4ht.env
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex4ht/base/win32/tex4ht.env)
Entering test.lg
Entering test.css
Entering test.tmp

E:\>
```

any one know how should i do ?
anyway i should first get html file, no matter how bad look it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works fine, please pass the conversion command what you tried, I've tried with:

`htlatex texfilename "xhtml,mathml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p`"

and the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd" > 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,mathml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2017-07-27 16:26:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >Hello there. This is a test of <!--l. 4--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="inline" ><msubsup><mrow 
><mi 
>x</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mi 
>i</mi></mrow><mrow 
><mn>2</mn></mrow></msubsup 
> <mo 
class="MathClass-rel">=</mo> <mn>3</mn></math>,
where
<!--tex4ht:inline--></p><!--l. 5--><math 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"  
display="block" >
                            <msubsup><mrow 
><mo 
class="MathClass-op">&#x222B;
 <!--nolimits--></mo><!--nolimits--></mrow><mrow 
><mn>0</mn></mrow><mrow 
><mi 
>&#x221E;</mi></mrow></msubsup 
><mi 
>f</mi><mrow ><mo 
class="MathClass-open">&#x0028;</mo><mrow><mi 
>x</mi></mrow><mo 
class="MathClass-close">&#x0029;</mo></mrow> <mo 
class="MathClass-rel">=</mo> <mn>1</mn><mo 
class="MathClass-punc">.</mo>
</math>
<!--l. 5--><p class="nopar" > </p> 
</body></html>
```

And for Word conversion try with `-oolatex` but I am not sure whether it can convert with MathML tag

And my .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210) (preloaded format=latex 2017.4.11)  27 JUL 2017 16:26
entering extended mode
**\makeatletter\def\HCode{\futurelet\HCode\HChar}\def\HChar{\ifx\HCode\def\HCod
e##1{\Link##1}\expandafter\HCode\else\expandafter\Link\fi}\def\Link#1.a.b.c.{\g
@addto@macro\@documentclasshook{\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}}\let\HCode\doc
umentstyle\def\documentstyle{\let\documentstyle\HCode\expandafter\def\csname te
x4ht\endcsname{#1,html}\def\HCode####1{\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\@ifnextchar[{\HC
ode}{\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\makeatother\HCode xhtml,mathml.a.b.c.\input  sam
ple
(sample.tex ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
```

Comment: i try these several command, i did not find the HTML file in the current folder.                                                               "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex.bat" test.tex 

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htxelatex.bat" test.tex 

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htlatex" test.tex "html,xml"

C:\Documents htlatex Myresume.tex "html,word"

"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\tex4ht\htxelatex" test

Comment: If you are using MikTeX as default, then why you are calling so many .bat files? And why are you calling from the installation path? Try with the command what I have suggested...

Comment: i just tried with the command you suggested, still there is no HTML file in the current folder. I guess, the command is right, but still there is something wrong, which i could not figure it out.

Comment: Also donot give the file name extension as .tex htlatex test "xhtml,mathml" " -cunihft" "-cvalidate -p"

Comment: mercy boucoup. but still there is no output file. maybe it is about my system or something else.

Comment: also, what i get is different from your code, still it is more or less same as the before.

Comment: What version of MikTeX you are using? I am using MikTeX Version 2.9

Comment: it is also miktex version 2.9, i download it two month ago. i also update it today.

Comment: I have posted .log file with my answer, please check the same with yours...

Comment: maybe this is the problem, i do not have a log file produced when i try htlatex . i only have .log file or .gz file when i compile it into pdf version, succeed. maybe there should be something telling it to generate .log file .html file which is missing.

Comment: What OS you are using? I am using Windows7 Pro...

Comment: i am also using windows 7 professional

Comment: ok, i found the problem . it is about how to switch to the current folder path. i move the .tex file to the default path. i found the html file.  so thank for your advice. if you have some good advice for how to change it to the current path using dos command

Comment: But the conversion should work where ever you keep the file, better to reinstall the MikTeX with admin rights and check...

Comment: yes it works now. although still has someproblem. two main problem is the figure problem and the biblo citation. i need work on that further. i think this is quitet good tool .s

Comment: Glad to hear that it is working for you... TeX4ht is a very good conversion tool when compare to others like tth, hevea, lxir, etc...